# Why is the independent constant of the differential equation not equal to the order of the differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I remember a conclusion: the number of independent constants in differential equations is equal to the order of the differential equation.

However, 23 independent constants are generated after the following fourth-order differential equation is solved.

```
DSolve[{D[2 D[ω[x, t], {x, 2}], {x, 2}] + D[ω[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0}, ω[x, t], {x, t}]
DSolve::lpdeprtclr: General solution is not available for the given linear partial differential equation. Returning a particular solution.
Out:= {{ω[x, t] -> 
   1/1680 (1680 C[23] t^2 x^4 - 1411200 C[8] t^2 x^3 - 
      470400 C[17] t^3 x^3 - 604800 C[7] t^2 x^2 - 
      201600 C[16] t^3 x^2 - 201600 C[6] t^2 x - 67200 C[15] t^3 x - 
      40320 C[5] t^2 - 13440 C[14] t^3 - 6720 C[23] t^4 + 
      1680 C[17] t x^7 + 1680 C[16] t x^6 + 1680 C[15] t x^5 + 
      1680 C[14] t x^4 + 1680 C[13] t x^3 + 1680 C[12] t x^2 + 
      1680 C[11] t x + 1680 C[10] t - C[23] x^8 + 1680 C[8] x^7 + 
      1680 C[7] x^6 + 1680 C[6] x^5 + 1680 C[5] x^4 + 1680 C[4] x^3 + 
      1680 C[3] x^2 + 1680 C[2] x + 1680 C[1])}}
```

We can see that the number of independent constants in the solution of this differential equation is far greater than the order of this differential equation. I want to know the relationship between the number of independent constants in the solution of a differential equation and the order of the differential equation.

*Version information: "12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)"*

Comment: This is not an ordinary differential equation but a partial differential equation (and of a quite unconventional type). I expect that initial and boundary conditions are required to make the solution unique. So there should be in fact an inifinite-dimensional manifold of  solutions... I am also puzzled why _Mathematica_ would generate this output. I cannot reproduce it with version 12.0.

Comment: With v12.1 along with this result I get a warning **"DSolve::lpdeprtclr: General solution is not available for the given linear partial differential equation. Returning a particular solution."** The solution given does satisfy the equation.

Comment: @BobHanlon There is indeed a warning message. I have added it to the problem statement.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The partial solution looks like the result of the advances in the asymptotic solvers in V12.1.  I’m a bit puzzled whether it is useful. Perhaps you are, too.

Comment: This PDE is, of course, solved trivially in Fourier space.  There is a 1D continuum of solutions.

Comment: Alternatively, the PDE is satisfied by all polynomials in {x, t} such that `x` is of third order or less, or `t` is of first order or less.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really not a Mathematica question (or if it is, it's a typography error).

Answer (score 2):

Try (version 12.0, sorry overlooked the version issue)

```
DSolve[{Derivative[0, 2][ω][x, t] +2 Derivative[4, 0 ][ω][x, t][x, t] == 0}, ω[x,t], {x, t}]
(*{{ω[x, t] ->     C[1][x] + t C[2][x] + Inactive[Integrate][Inactive[Integrate][-2\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ω\),TagBox[RowBox[{"(",RowBox[{"4", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, K[1]][x, K[1]], {K[1], 1, K[2]}], {K[2],1, t}]}}*)
```

Comment: Version 12.1 gives the same answer, but only because your version of the PDE contains a syntax error, `Derivative[4, 0][ω][x, t][x, t]`.  I am amazed that Mathematica does not catch it!

Comment: @bbgodfrey Realy amazing, thanks! After correcting the syntax error v12.0 can't evaluate the pde anymore !!

Comment: Look closely at your answer and you will see that it actually is not valid, because it gives `ω` in terms of `Derivative[4, 0][ω][x, K[1]]` and also contains a spurious extra `[x, K[1]]`.  possibly, Mathematica interpreted your PDE as an ODE with `Derivative[4, 0][ω][x, t][x, t]` as an unknown function of `t`, and solved it simply by twice integrating the equation.